# elastic apm, turn off ssl verification

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

logstash 's elasticsearch output has option to turn off SSL verification

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-ssl_certificate_verification

Is there a similar option for apm?

Elasticsearch is using self signed certificate, and apm is complaining when connecting to ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Elastic APM agents, with the exception of the RUM JavaScript agent, have a [`verify_server_cert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/config-reporter.html#config-verify-server-cert) configuration variable. You can set this to `false` to disable server TLS certificate verification.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, I want APM => ES . 
ES has security turned on (but with self signed certificate) and APM is having trouble connecting to ES.

Answer (score 1):

I am using docker-compose

and the following option doesn't work. I think its a bug for apm..
When I use same option in apm-server.yml it works fine.

```
environment:
  - output.elasticsearch.protocol=https
  - output.elasticsearch.username=$USERNAME
  - output.elasticsearch.password=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
  - output.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode=none
```

Comment: The issue here is that apm-server does not look for configuration in environment variables. You can pass configuration through the `command` with the `-E` flag. e.g. "-E output.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode=none". See https://github.com/elastic/apm-contrib/blob/master/stack/docker-compose.yml for an example.